# How to stop the Duplicate data in a mongodb using save command

Tags: mongodb

```
var newUser = new User({ countryCode: countryCode, phoneNumber: 
phoneNumber,simSerial:simSerial,emailAddress:emailAddress });
newUser.save((err, user) =>{
console.log("saved sucessfully")
})
```

Here i'm using save command to save the data in a collection, but some times it creates duplicates

Is it possible to add `upsert:true` in `save` command ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use Unique Index on the collection link https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/

Comment: Can you please tell me how to use unique index in above code

Comment: can you please tell which connector are you using? mongoose or some other connector with nodejs.

Comment: You need to open the  mongo shell: and use the following command `db.Your_collection_name.createIndex( { "Your_unique_field": 1 }, { unique: true } )`

Comment: But i want in api calling ,not in the mongo shell @smn_onrocks

Comment: @susmithapanda u are not getting it if you impose a unique constraint in the collection lvl then It will not let you insert duplicate doc. for that now special API call would be required. Imposing the unique index is 1 time job please go through the link previously i sheared with you

Comment: i used this `db.Your_collection_name.createIndex( { "Your_unique_field": 1 }, { unique: true } )` but i'm getting this error `TypeError: _UsersSchema2.default.createIndex is not a function
`

Comment: Can you please share what exact command you are trying

Comment: `User.createIndex({ "phoneNumber": 1 },{ unique: true })`   User is my collection name, unique field is phoneNumber

Comment: you should use `db.User.createIndex({ "phoneNumber": 1 },{ unique: true })`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186029/discussion-between-susmitha-panda-and-smn-onrocks).